# Making waterproof LED circuit

Tags: led, circuits, waterproof

If I am trying to make an led necklace with a few LEDs connected in parallel(each one separated by a little bit of wire) that connects back to a battery pack with 3 AAs, how can I make the necklace water proof, or at least water resistant enough to protect against rain.

Comment: i think that you need to be more concerned with sweat than with rain

Comment: Frankly, as long as the necklace is resistant to sweat I'd be happy.  The choice of protection is important for allergic reactions.

Comment: Parallel LEDs is usually a bad idea.

Comment: @Andyaka Why is that? I was under the impression that with series leds, I would need a really high voltage once the amount of leds adds up. So if I had 10 3V leds wouldn't my battery voltage have to be 30V?

Comment: That’s quite true but with series LEDs you only need one current control circuit whereas with parallel LEDs you need.......

Comment: @Andyaka Could you elaborate, or provide a link to something so that I can know what you're talking about